# NSInvalidArgumentException: object cannot be nil

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, null

I am relatively new to Xcode and am trying to write an app that will play a video from iTunes from a tutorial but my app keeps crashing.

It is giving me the error code:

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

I used breakpoints and found where the problem is but I'm not sure how to fix it. The line that is giving me problems is:

```
[list addObject:[item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL]];
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Below is the .m file code:

```
@implementation iPodLibrary

+(NSArray *) movieList {

    NSMutableArray *list =

    [[[NSMutableArray allocWithZone:NULL] init] autorelease];

    MPMediaQuery *query = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];

    [query addFilterPredicate:[MPMediaPropertyPredicate

                               predicateWithValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:(MPMediaTypeAny ^ MPMediaTypeAnyAudio)]
                               forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyMediaType]];

    for (MPMediaItem* item in [query items]) {
        [list addObject:[item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL]];
    }
    [query release];

    return list;    
}

+ (NSString *) movieTitle:(NSURL *)aURL {

    NSString *aTitle = nil;

    if (aURL) {

        AVAsset* aAsset = [[AVURLAsset allocWithZone:NULL]
                           initWithURL:aURL options:nil];

        for (AVMetadataItem* metadata in [aAsset commonMetadata]) {

            if ([[metadata commonKey] isEqualToString:AVMetadataCommonKeyTitle]) {

                aTitle = [metadata stringValue];

                break;              
            }
        }       
    }

    return aTitle;    
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Check that [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL] is actually returning a value. NSMutableArray does not allow the addition of a nil value with the addObject method. See [NSMutableArray addObject: documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/addObject%3a)

You can check if it is null like so:

```
for (MPMediaItem* item in [query items]) {
    id itemValue = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
    [list addObject:itemValue]; // break point this line and see what itemValue is.
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I put that in and it showed that list is coming back 0.  I'm still unsure of how to fix it though. The code matches the sample project I'm basing it off of but even that doesn't whorl in mine. It's something in the iPodLibrary.h&.m that isn't working because that it where it's supposed to be getting into the iTunes library but it doesn't. Do you have any other ideas on how to fix it? Thank you again I appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you verified there is something in the iTunes library for it to return?

Comment: Yes. It is supposed to bring up movies from iTunes and I am running/testing it on my iPad and I made sure to put movies on it so it would have something to return.

Answer (score 0):

In Objective C you cannot put nil values into `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`.